# no-param-reassign: What is a practical, real-life example of a problem caused by reassigning parameters?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I see a lot of questions about best practices for complying with the `no-param-reassign` linting rule, but no/fewer requests to illustrate the rationale for the rule.

Claims like 'Assignment to variables declared as function parameters can be misleading and lead to confusing behavior' are all well and good, but what are some real-life practical examples of problems caused by not adhering to this rule?

Note that I'm not asking for opinions about whether this rule is good. I am asking for concrete examples of this "confusing behavior" so I can understand the rationale for the rule better.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

Comment: Linked from the rule's page: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/10/javascript-don-t-reassign-your-function-arguments/

Comment: @jmargolisvt That part of the argumentation is rubbish however and does not apply to modern environments (which use strict mode).

Comment: In general, the parameters are considered as constants that always refer to the values that were passed the function. If you've got a long function body and some parts overwrite the parameter variables, the reader may get confused.

Comment: @Quentin - I am aware of the eslint documentation - I quoted from it directly in my OP. If you read my question carefully, you'll see that the docs do not answer it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I am not asking for contrived examples that illustrate the fact that the arguments object is mutated - I am asking for real-world examples of this causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the principle of least surprise. The nice thing about modern JavaScript is that for non-parameter variables, if you see a `const` variable, you don't have to analyze the entire function to know what you can expect its value to be, so you can understand the code more easily. It can put your mind at ease, in short. If something is defined with `let` or `var`, then you know you have the mental burden of checking the code for any reassignments. This is why personally I recommend avoiding `let` or `var` almost all of the time.

Unfortunately, with parameters, you don't have the opportunity to declare whether they're reassignable. It is a rare practice to reassign parameters since the semantics of a parameter and assignable variable are now conflated. Personally, I don't think it's a huge deal for shorter functions, but where mutation can really bite you is in longer functions where you can't see all the code on the screen. Imagine you're trying to debug this code. You see an error being thrown like "Invalid purchase price". You find that error message at the bottom of a long function:

```
async function purchase(price, tax, roundUp) {
  // ...

  if (typeof price !== 'number') {
    throw new Error('Invalid purchase price');
  }
}
```

OK, you might say, let's see if anyone's not passing a number into `purchase`. So you find all references to `purchase`, and trace back where the first parameter comes from in all cases, and oddly you come to the conclusion that your code is haunted because you're never passing a non-numeric price to the code. However, you probably forgot that `price` could have changed at any time in the function, so you missed scrolling up and finding:

```
price = price + tax;
```

Someone passed a non-number into `tax`, causing an error on a check for the `price` parameter, which might take us some time to figure out.

Imagine how much clearer the code is if we saw:

```
const totalPrice = price + tax;

/* ... */

if (typeof totalPrice !== 'number') {
  throw new Error('Invalid purchase price');
}
```

We'd know now that we need to check both the `price` and `tax` parameters.

This is the sort of "confusing behavior" they're talking about and why discouraging the atypical practice can be valuable.

Comment: Thank you, that was illuminating ~